# Azure AD B2C - b2clogin.com CORS

Tags: azure, cors, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

Having tried multiple OIDC auth libraries I still have no luck with my angular app. I ALWAYS get this error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://{tenant}.b2clogin.com/{tenant-GUID}/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration' from origin 'https://192.168.3.2:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Is there a way to set CORS?

Any ideas?

Comment: Wait, why is this an ajax call? Shouldn't you redirect the browser to the b2clogin.com endpoint so the user goes through the authentication flow hosted on Microsoft property? Moreover, what are you planning to do with the metadata, are you verifying the token signature in the browser? Doesn't it defeat the whole purpose of validation if the user is able to break and alter the validation code?

Comment: I managed to make Azure B2C users manager and complete authentication+authorization solution with .Net Core 3.1 + Angular. The only library that really works is MSAL.js (for js or for angular). I tried other 2 libs (oidc-...something from Manfred Steyer and another from Damien Bod, both for angular) but had no luck with B2C. And believe me I've put a lot of effort!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CORS is allowed for the `/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration` endpoint but I believe it's blocked if the browser origin (e.g. "https://192.168.3.2:4200") is `localhost` or an IP address.

Comment: it's also blocked for localhost then :(

Comment: Hi @alvipeo: Can you add a host mapping to your local system to work around this?

Comment: Hi @ChrisPadgett, did this finally work? I am having the same issue